# Regex match exact pattern but only last occurence

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression that parses the following kind of string:

```
My Name Here(123456789) some_code[some_other_code]
```

The format is relatively easy:

- My Name Here is a Steam name (which can be pretty much anything I think).
- This is followed by a number between parentheses. There is no space between the name and the opening parenthesis.
- Followed by a space.
- Followed by a code name (which I don't think can contain spaces) "some_code" in this case.
- Followed by another code (again no spaces probably) between block parentheses "[some_other_code]" in this case.

I want to capture all four:

- "My Name Here"
- 123456789
- some_code
- some_other_code

The following regex works:

```
(.*?)\(([0-9]*)\) (.*?)\[(.*?)\]
```

The problem is that the first 'My Name Here' part may also contain a number between parentheses for all I know... Instead of "My Name Here" it could be "Nick(123) (456) Abcd". And that does not match properly...

The same regex matches this:

```
Nick(123) (456) Abcd(123456789) some_code[some_other_code]
```

And the first capture group now captures only "Nick" (while it should capture "Nick(123) (456) Abcd") while the second group captures 123 as the number, while it should capture the last occurence 123456789.

In other words, I want only the last occurrence of (([0-9]*)) to match as the second group, not the first one...

I think I need to use look back or something, but I have no clue how to implement this.... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `?` quantifier present inside the first capturing group. So that it would capture all the characters from the start [greedily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (*longest match*) upto the last `(` parenthesis.

```
(.*)\(([0-9]*)\) (.*?)\[(.*?)\]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qW8wQ6/5)

Comment: Sweet, that was easier than I expected... Thanks!